# Extract the first item of the list from nested lists

Tags: r, list, datatable

I have the following column in my data table (there are more lists inside, but I just provide it simplified)

```
n  col1
1  list(c("1", "2", "3", "5"), c("5", "6", "8", "8"))
2  list(c("9", "10", "11", "12"), c("13", "14", "15", "16"))
```

And I want to extract the first value from each of the lists in the row. So, I want the outcome

```
n  col2
1  c("1", "5")
2  c("9", "13")
```

I looked into many examples here and on the internet about nested lists, it seems that it should be easy, but it doesn't seem that it works quite as I intend it to. I use the following variants of code

```
   1. dt$col2 <-sapply(dt$col1 , "[[", 1)
  `2. dt$col2 <- lapply(dt$col1, function(l) l[[1]])`
  `3. dt$col2 <- rvest::pluck(dt$col1, 1)`
```

But they all give the same output which is basically the first list

```
n  col2
1  c("1", "2", "3", "5")
2  c("9", "10", "11", "12")
```

There must be something wrong with my understanding, but I can't get why it happens this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
dt$col2 <-sapply(dt$col1 , "[", 1)
```

(The elements of your lists are not lists, just vectors, so one bracket is fine)

EDIT :

For a column inside a data.table :

```
 dt$col2 <- sapply(dt$col1,function(x){sapply(x,'[',1)})
```

Comment: It still gives the same output :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that it was a data.table.
try : dt$col2 <- sapply(dt$col1,function(x){sapply(x,function(y),'[',1)})

Comment: Thank you!I unfortunately still don't get it. Probably it is just because I am new to R. Now it says unexpected token "," in this place: function(y),

Comment: Lol sorry, edited again.
What is happening is that you apply to each element of df1$col1 the function whcih returns sapply(x,'[',1).
(Your dataframe is a bit wierd, so the solution is too !)